Compact complex manifolds with nef canonical bundle have nonnegative Kodaira dimension
Let $X$ be a compact Kähler manifold with nef canonical bundle. The (Kähler extension of the) abundance conjecture asserts that $K_X$ is semi-ample, and thus $K_X^{\otimes m}$ admits a section for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence, the Kodaira dimension of $X$ is nonnegative $\kappa(X) \geq 0$.

I would like to know the proof (if it exists) of the following assertion: Let X be a compact complex manifold (not necessarily Kähler) with $K_X$ nef. Then the Kodaira dimension of $X$ is nonnegative $\kappa(X) \geq 0$.

It is not clear to me from the definition of nef, even for compact Kähler manifolds, that some tensor multiple must admit a section. Is there a direct proof, even for compact Kähler manifolds, that avoids abundance?

This is not known even for smooth projective varieties, so how could it exist a "direct proof"?

@abx So a projective manifold with nef canonical bundle may have negative Kodaira dimension? Does this not violate the fundamental premise of the minimal model program?

@ABBC: abx said "not known", not "not true". Your assertion is part of what is known as the "nonvanishing conjecture".

The statement that you wrote ($K_X$ nef implies $\kappa(X)\geq 0$) is currently conjectured to be true but unknown if $X$ is projective, and also if $X$ is Kähler.  However, it is known to be false if $X$ is a general compact complex manifold. There are many counterexamples, the easiest ones are the Inoue-Bombieri surfaces (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inoue_surface)

Thank you @LazzaroCampeotti

Thank you @YangMills for both the clarification of the conjecture and the counterexample.

@YangMills Do you happen to know if the Inoue-Bombieri surface is the only class VII surface with $K_X$ nef (or in this case, semipositive)?

Yes, the only class VII surfaces with $K_X$ nef are Inoue-Bombieri (and these even have $K_X$ semipositive).

@YangMills Cheers!

Proof sketch: 1) $K_X$ nef implies $X$ minimal, because $K_X\cdot C\geq 0$ for any curve $C$. 2) if $X$ is minimal and class VII then $(K_X^2)=-b_2(X)$ (due to Kodaira). Since $K_X$ is nef, we have $(K_X^2)\geq 0$, and so $b_2(X)$ must be zero. 3) By Bogomolov, Li-Yau-Zheng, Teleman, this implies $X$ is either Hopf of Inoue-Bombieri. 4) if $X$ is Hopf then $H^0(X,-mK_X)\neq 0$ for some $m\geq 1$, see e.g. Teleman "The pseudo-effective cone...", Remark 4.3.


Take $D\in |-mK_X|$ nontrivial effective divisor, and $\omega$ a Gauduchon metric on $X$, then $0<\int_D\omega=-m\int_X\omega\wedge c_1(K_X),$ which contradicts that $\int_X\omega\wedge c_1(K_X)\geq 0$ since $K_X$ is nef.

